# ESLint `no-useless-constructor`: how to ignore constructors with property assignments

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint, typescript-eslint

In NestJS, the pattern in the constructor is quite common:

```
constructor(private service: MyService) {}
```

I've got a rule in ESlint that says that [useless constructors are an error](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-useless-constructor/):

```
"no-useless-constructor": "error"
```

Since constructors that assign properties aren't really useless, is there a way to ignore this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn `eslint/no-useless-constructor` rule off and instead use the one coming from [`@typescript-eslint`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-useless-constructor/)

```
    "no-useless-constructor": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-constructor": "error"
```

Comment: Which is explained in the docs OP linked (https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-useless-constructor/#options)